# Test AD credentials with java using ADFS

Tags: java, authentication, adfs

I would like to produce java code that could attempt to check the validity of a Domain username/password pair against ADFS

I was given an URL to a federationmetadata.xml (apparently it is ADFS 4.0 -  2016).

I don't want SSO nor a fancy login page, I just want a service to test my login credentials.

As a confessed ignorant on SAML and ADFS I'm having a hard time narrowing the propper possible apporach(es)

Thank you

Comment: This site is not used as a means to provide code for your needs, but rather getting help with what you have tried so far.  If you have code you tried, please provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

ADFS is an IDP that provides SSO.

So when you use ADFS, you get a login screen.

There is no way to hook in a third-party component as you require.

What you need to do is go straight to AD via LDAP as per [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C).

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I think I will wise SPRING's SAML capabilities and redirect my users to theyr organixation's ADFS login